# Speed-up multiple evaluations of NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I run a shooting method that evaluates the same NDSolve many times with different parameter values.  I assume that Mathematica spends most of the time for symbolic interpretation of NDSolve input and choosing the right algorithm.  Can I improve the speed by, somehow, pre-compiling NDSolve (or giving any low-level options)?   I have tried to use ParametricNDSolve hoping that some optimization was done there, but it works even slower!
Thanks,
Sergey

Comment: Where is your try in *Mathematica*?

Comment: I would have said, given the little information above, that `ParametricNDSolve` was your best bet.  Normally the symbolic processing takes at most a few milliseconds, but that's for a relatively small system, say a few lines long.  I would guess that most of the time is spent crunching numbers.  But again, with no code, I have no basis for that.